# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null using onclick

Tags: onclick

I am trying to change the 1 to x. I am getting an error. Perhaps there is an easier way.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="id1" onclick="changeText(this.id); this.onclick=null;">1</div>
    </div>
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeText(selectedId) {
  document.getElementById("selectedId").innerHTML = "x"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get an element that has `id="selectedId"` & there isn't one.

Remove the quotation marks in your JavaScript so it is just:

```
document.getElementById(selectedId).innerHTML = "x"
```

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle to try it: https://jsfiddle.net/thiosin/97utg036/8/